# Flowplayer only works on localhost. Doesn't work on server

Tags: localhost, flowplayer

I have a bit of a problem with setting flowplayer right. When I worked on localhost everything seemed to work fine but when I copied my site to server player won't load properly.

The anchor tag is re-sized to set parameters and is filled with object tag but nothing is displayed. Interesting thing is that when part of page with flowplayer is behind firebug or browser window is re-sized then player loads properly.
How I can fix this problem ?

I load player with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $f("movie", {src: "public/flash/flowplayer.swf", wmode: "transparent"}, {
  clip: {
          autoPlay: false,
          autoBuffering: true
         }                          
   }           
); });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make a htaccess file in the same folder as your flowplayer is

`Options +FollowSymLinks`
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteRule . - [E=no-gzip:1]`

that worked for me.